# RabbitMQ message not being sent to Dead Letter Queue on Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I have this RabbitMQ Spring Boot Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    // Main queue configuration
    @Value("${rabbitmq.main.messages.queue}")
    private String mainQueueName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.main.exchange.queue}")
    private String mainExchangeName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.main.routing.key}")
    private String mainRoutingKey;

    // DLQ configuration
    @Value("${rabbitmq.dlq.messages.queue}")
    private String dlqQueueName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.dlq.exchange.queue}")
    private String dlqExchangeName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.dlq.routing.key}")
    private String dlqRoutingKey;

    // Connectivity         
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String rabbitmqHost;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
    private int rabbitmqPort;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String rabbitmqUsername;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String rabbitmqPassword;

    // Not delivered messages, will be used eventually
    @Value("${rabbitmq.not.delivered.messages.queue}")
    private String notDeliveredMessagesQueue;

    // status with delivered messages (callback default)
    @Value("${rabbitmq.delivered.messages.queue}")
    private String deliveredMessagesQueue;
                
    @Bean
    DirectExchange deadLetterExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(dlqExchangeName);
    }
    
    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(mainExchangeName);
    }   
    
    @Bean
    Queue dlq() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(dlqQueueName).build();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable(mainQueueName)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "deadLetterExchange")
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", dlqQueueName).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    Binding deadLetterBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(dlq()).to(deadLetterExchange()).with(dlqRoutingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with(mainQueueName);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitmqHost);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        admin.declareQueue(queue());
        admin.declareExchange(exchange());
        admin.declareBinding(binding());
        return admin;
    }
    
    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }   
}
```

The problem is that when some exception is launched the message is not sent to DLQ queue.

Consumer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = { "${rabbitmq.main.messages.queue}" })
public void recievedMessage(@Payload Mensagem item, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws InvalidMessageException {
    if (item.getIdCliente().equals("69")) {
        logger.info("Something went wrong to: " + item);
        throw new InvalidMessageException();
    } else {
        logger.info("==> Message consumed successfully: " + item);
    }
}
```

This is the configuration I have on my application.properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=3s
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=2
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier=2
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-interval=10s
```

When I throw an exception on purpose just to see the message moving to DLQ nothing happens. What's wrong here? What am I forgetting here?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.default-requeue-rejected=false
```

to your application.properties. I think the problem is that the failed deliveries are being requeued instead of being sent to the DLQ.

Comment: Or you can throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.